# how to change background position when focus on input

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="field">
    <input name="password" type="password" />
</div>
```

I want to change the background image's position of the field div when there is focus on input. Any idea to do it with jquery? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried this, but I think the following should work:

```
$('input:password').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().css({'background-position': 'Xpx Ypx'});
    }).blur(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().css({'background-position': 'Xpx Ypx'});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for the `focus` event on your password input, and then change the `background-position` CSS property on target using jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
$('div.field input[name="password"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.field').css('background-position', '10px 10px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.field input').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus')
});
```

Then just set the .field.focus classes background position.

Comment: This solution will work for all input fields, and allows you to keep your presentational markup separate from your functional jQuery.